# NAS wifi connection slow at Night

Tags: nas, mybook, wifi-transfer

I'm using a MyBookLive NAS since 2011. Since around two weeks, the video playback by using wifi is really bad. Buffering etc.
I've had the same problem some time ago, but it disappeared. But now it's back and I'd like to know what's the cause.

Also: Currently that only happens after ca 10pm. I've tested it today. At 7pm, it worked without any problem.

My internet connection is also stable and not different between 5pm and 9pm.

Also the LAN connection is stable to, all the time. Only wifi seems to be unstable.

I'm using the MyBookLive in a 2.4Ghz environment and am using an iPad and an iPhone to connect(VLC player SMB)

As said: The internet Connection is stable. Only the internal wifi between the nas and my iphone seems to be slow.

What can be the cause?

**Edit:** 
I've tested my wifi on my windows pc and there, the playback works without any issue.

Comment: Other users, interference, background tasks, etc.

Comment: Interference? Somebody is turning on something electrical somewhere at 10 pm?

Comment: I checked something else also. And it's interesting: I've tested my wifi on my windows pc and there, the playback works without any issue.

Comment: Is the phone plugged in? If so it might be choosing that time to backup, slowing itself down & also causing more congestion on the wifi. Alternatively, something else may be backing up at that time.